# datetime values accidentally being converted to integers during reassignment

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following `df`,

```
inv_date
24/01/2008
nan
nan
nan
13/08/2007
02/04/2007
02/04/2007
03/04/2007
03/04/2007
03/04/2007
04/04/2007
09/08/2007 12:16:55
```

The values in `inv_date` are all strings, I tried to use some code to convert them into `datetime64`; `format` in inferred from `inv_date` as the most common date format, and the reason I don't slice `str[:10]` the `inv_date`, is because the majority of values are not always just day/month/year, sometimes it can also include hour/min/sec, so slice the values to a fixed position is not ideal;

```
failed_rows = pd.isnull(pd.to_datetime(data.df['inv_date'], errors='coerce', format='%d/%m/%Y'))

if failed_rows.sum():
   df.loc[failed_rows, 'inv_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[failed_rows, 'inv_date'], errors='coerce').dt.floor('D')

   df.loc[~failed_rows, 'inv_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[~failed_rows, 'inv_date'], errors='coerce', format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

it turns out to be

```
inv_date
1201132800000000000
None
None
None
1186963200000000000
1175472000000000000
1175472000000000000
1175558400000000000
1175558400000000000
1175558400000000000
1175644800000000000
1189209600000000000
```

The ideal result should look like,

```
inv_date
24/01/2008
NaT
NaT
NaT
13/08/2007
02/04/2007
02/04/2007
03/04/2007
03/04/2007
03/04/2007
04/04/2007
09/08/2007
```

with `dtype` `datetime64`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert to datetime, normalize, and convert back to string. NaTs are retained.

```
(pd.to_datetime(df['inv_date'], errors='coerce')
   .dt.normalize()
   .dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))

0     24/01/2008
1            NaT
2            NaT
3            NaT
4     13/08/2007
5     04/02/2007
6     04/02/2007
7     04/03/2007
8     04/03/2007
9     04/03/2007
10    04/04/2007
11    08/09/2007
Name: inv_date, dtype: object
```

Comment: how to make the `dtype` to `datetime64` in this case for `inv_date`?

Comment: @daiyue Remove the `.dt.strftime(...)`